# VBA-Change color of cells based on value in particular cell

Tags: vba, excel

I want to change the background colors of cells `A2:C2` based on the value of cell `D2`.

This also applies to the relative cells in rows 3,4, and 5.

If the value in cell `D#` is 1, I'd like color x. If the value is 2, I'd like color y, if the value is 3, I'd like the color z.

If it makes a difference, the target range (`A2:D6`) will be in a table format.

I'd like this subroutine to execute upon opening the workbook. I know where to put that subroutine so don't sweat instructing me how.

I've done this with conditional formatting, but it'd be nice to have some VBA I can copy-pasta into future reports.

Comment: Conditional formatting will automatically adjust. Why use VBA, which would have to run again and again and would be less efficient? Conditional formatting can also be copied into other files.

Comment: It'd be helpful to learn some syntax. I'm sure I could morph it into something more practical someday. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck on your code?
What are you trying to code on top of native copy-paste?

Comment: @RikSportel I don't know how to create the array/loop for a `for/each` statement. Thanks.

Comment: @teylyn Array/loop is my hunch as to how to best write the code, but it does not mean it is the best way. I don't want to limit the answerer's solutions so I choose intentionally not to be specific. Thanks.

Comment: Microsoft example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353(v=office.11).aspx
Great training/explanation: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/loops.htm 
Why you should just use conditional formatting: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/VBALoops.htm 
Please let us know where you get stuck after you start coding if you decide to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use Conditional formatting, but this works:

```
Sub ColorMeElmo()
   Dim i As Long, r1 As Range, r2 As Range

   For i = 2 To 5
      Set r1 = Range("D" & i)
      Set r2 = Range("A" & i & ":C" & i)
      If r1.Value = 1 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
      If r1.Value = 2 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbBlue
      If r1.Value = 3 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbYellow
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Precisely what I needed. You're excellent, thanks for the elmo sub.

Comment: @Gary's student. I had a similar problem today and it took me some time to fix it by just using conditionals. It is okay now, but this post is precisely what I did in a 40-minute-work. Now, similar problems will take 30 seconds. Thank you too Gary.

Comment: Conditional formatting can give you a range between 2 colors, or even 3 colors. When you want 4 or more, you either split cells into multiple groups, or turn to code like this. Good to have.