# excel vba, how to make a mcro that will change the color of cell when i type in any initials(like AD, FS)

Tags: excel, vba

we didn't do VBA yet, so I don't know how to do that

```
Sub color()

    Range("A1:E5").Select
    For Each Cell In Selection
        If Cell.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbYellow Then
            Cell.Clear
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA-Change color of cells based on value in particular cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142985/vba-change-color-of-cells-based-on-value-in-particular-cell)

Comment: It sounds like you could do this with just conditional formatting,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the code below into the relevant worksheet module, in the `Worksheet_Change` event.

What it does, is if you type in a cell "AD" or "FS" it will color it Yellow.

Since I've used `Select Case` you can add more scenarios in the future quite easily.

***Code***

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "AD", "FS"
            Target.Interior.color = XlRgbColor.rgbYellow

        Case Else 
            ' add more scenarios in the future

    End Select
End If

End Sub
```