# I want to colour the Yes as green and No with Red colour.But the code that I hae written is not working for me

Tags: vba

"yes" and "no" are in column L and I want to colour the "yes" with green and "No" with red.

I have written the below code which is not working for me.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Set MyPlage = Range("L3:L200")

For Each cell In MyPlage

Select Case cell.Value

Case Is = "Yes"
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 10

Case Is = "No"
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

Case Else
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone


End Select
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What problem are you having?  (E.g. the code works for me, except the "No" is coloured yellow.  Is that your problem, i.e. that it is yellow instead of red?  Or is it something else.)

Answer (score 0):

Example of function that change color :

```
Sub ChangeColor()
lRow = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MR = Range("L2:L" & lRow)
For Each cell In MR
If cell.Value = "Yes" Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
If cell.Value = "No" Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Next
End Sub
```

Or other way => [Vba Change Color Of Cells Based On Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142985/vba-change-color-of-cells-based-on-value-in-particular-cell)

Comment: Actually i am comparing few cells and the output of comparison is coming as yes or no in the L column.But I want if I get yes then the background colour should change to green for that particular yes and if no then red.

Comment: you just change the cell.value by result of output => if output = "Yes" Then yourcell.Interior.ColorIndex = 10

Answer (score 0):

Is it simply that you test for "Yes" and wonder why "yes" and "YES" don't fire?
try

```
  If ucase(cell.Value) = "YES" Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
```